# An elementary conditional probability question

Tags: probability-theory

Let A and B be two independent events, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\cdot\mathbb{P}(B)$ also $\mathbb{P}(A\mid B)=P(A)$ and $P(B\mid A)=P(B)$.

**The first question:**
Is this correct that for any set $S$ 
$$
(1)\qquad \mathbb{P}(A\cap B\mid S)=\mathbb{P}(A\mid S)\cdot\mathbb{P}(B\mid S)?
$$

**The second question:**
Let me explain first how this question arises. There is such an article in wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering and in the section 
"Combining individual probabilities" the following formula is given 
$$
(2) \qquad p=\frac{p_1p_2\cdots p_N}{p_1p_2\cdots p_N+(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\cdots (1-p_N)}.
$$

The derivation of this formula should be based on the Bayes' theorem, however the proof is not placed there. Even more, in a text bellow the formula (2), one states that this formula is "... out of thin air" and in a deeper explanation on the link writes that formula (1) is correct... Something confusing here.
Trying to find out the formula (2) I want to ask:

Let $W_1,W_2,\ldots,W_N$ be a mutually independent events. Is this correct that for any set $S$
$$(3)\qquad
\mathbb{P}(S\mid W_1 \cap \ldots \cap W_N)=\\
=\frac{\mathbb{P}(W_1\mid S)\cdots\mathbb{P}(W_N\mid S)\cdot\mathbb{P}(S)}{\mathbb{P}(W_1\mid S)\cdots\mathbb{P}(W_N\mid S)\cdot\mathbb{P}(S)+(1-\mathbb{P}(W_1\mid S))\cdots(1-\mathbb{P}(W_N\mid S))\cdot(1-\mathbb{P}(S))}
$$
?

Comment: #2 is also false.  Again we can use the standard counterexample: flip two fair coins. $W_1$ is the event that the first coin is heads, $W_2$ is the event that the second coin is heads, and $S$ is the event that the two coins show different sides.  Then $P(S \mid W_1 \cap W_2) = 0$ whereas the right side is not zero.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.
If (1) and (3) equalities are incorrect, 
can there still be reasonable equality (2) in wikipedia?

Comment: The formula appears to describe the following thing: you have a bunch of tests: $1$ to $N$ which accept or reject emails as spam or not; it appears to be assumed that the outcomes of all of these tests are independent. If some tests are passed and some are failed, you are in an indeterminate case. The formula appears to compute the probability of passing all the tests given that you are in the determinate case. Whether this is meaningful, I leave to the computer science types to explain.